# "nodemon" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me reconoce ningún comando en la terminal, por ejemplo "nodemon", "create-react-app", entre otros, al ejecutarlos... y previamente los instalo globalmente. Pero al quererlos ejecutar no me los reconocen....

Alguna solucion?

Comment: Es posible que hayas cambiado la carpeta donde se guardan los ejecutables o las variables de entorno no están bien configuradas.

Comment: @Mateo Todo se esta guardando en el disco local C , no hace mucho funcionaba todo bien, de repente ya no me reconoce ningun comando...

Answer (score 5):

Tienes que instalarlo de forma global usando el comando

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoExQ.png]

En el

> package.json

Dentro del objeto `"scripts"` (crealo tal cual en la imagen se muestra si no lo tienes).

Pones el comando que usarás para ejecutar el test, en mi caso he puesto la palabra **"dev"** y a continuación el comando de nodemon.

Guardas el archivo package.json y en la consola para ejecutar el comando tienes que escribir, `npm run dev`

De esta forma no hace falta instalarte nodemon de forma global y puede uusarlo solo como dependencia de desarrollo.

Comment: Hola Ruben, primero, edita tu respuesta y quita el "meme", segundo, las explicaciones, el código y los mensajes de error, deben ir como texto, adapta tu respuesta a los requerimientos del sitio, y evitarás recibir votos negativos, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.